# python collision detect trouble

Tags: python, pygame

Being a begineer in python with some basic knowledge, i decided to expand this knowledge by making programs. In one such program, i found difficulties in collision detection. since i am using a .xml file most of my ideas seem not to work. The program is given below. can anyone help me with collision detect?

```
import pygame, time, os ,random, time
from pytmx import load_pygame

#____________________Variables_______________________

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,191,255)


#___________________Screen Init______________________

screenSize = (640,704)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screenSize)
pygame.display.set_caption("game")
screen.fill(black)
FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

#____________________Game Data_______________________

os.chdir("D:\Games\mageQuest\Data\Images")
Character_img = pygame.image.load("Character.png")


#__________________Commands Init_____________________

class game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop_ = 0
        self.game_disp = 0

    def loop(self):
        self.loop_ = self.loop_ + 1
        if self.loop_ == 50:
            self.game_disp = 1
            self.loop_ = 0

class load_map:
    def __init__(self):
        global map_name       
        global gameMap
        global x
        global y
        x = 100
        y = 69
        os.chdir("D:\Games\mageQuest\Data\Maps")
        map_list = os.listdir()
        print(map_list)
        #map_name = input("Enter map name: ")
        map_name = "map1"        
        gameMap = load_pygame(map_name+".tmx")     
    def create(self, x, y):
        image_none = gameMap.get_tile_image(1,1,0)
        images0 = []
        x_tmp = x
        y_tmp = y
        screen.fill(blue)
        while y_tmp - 44 != y:
            y_tmp = y_tmp + 1 
            x_tmp = x
            while x_tmp - 40 != x:        
                image = gameMap.get_tile_image(x_tmp,y_tmp,0)
                images0.append(image)
                x_tmp = x_tmp + 1           
        i = 0
        for y_ in range(44):
            for x_ in range(40):
                if images0[i] != gameMap.get_tile_image(1,1,0):
                    screen.blit(images0[i],(x_ * 16, y_ * 16))
                i = i + 1
        screen.blit(Character_img, (320, 352))

class character:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = y
        self.y = x
    def movement(self, key, x, y):
        print(x,y)
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            character.movement_1( x, y)
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            character.movement_2( x, y)
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            character.movement_3( x, y)
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            character.movement_4( x, y)
    def movement_1(self, x, y):
        y = y - 1
        time.sleep(0.25)
        self.dir = 1
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def movement_2(self, x, y):
        x = x - 1
        time.sleep(0.25)
        self.dir = 2
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def movement_3(self, x, y):
        y = y + 1
        time.sleep(0.25)
        self.dir = 3
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def movement_4(self, x, y):
        x = x + 1
        time.sleep(0.25)
        self.dir = 4
        self.x = x
        self.y = y



#____________________Main Loop_______________________



mageQuest = game()
world = load_map()
world.create(x, y)
character = character(x, y)


game_running = True
while game_running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        character.movement(event.key, x, y)
        x = character.x
        y = character.y

    mageQuest.loop()


    if mageQuest.game_disp == 1:
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)
        game_disp = 0
        world.create(x, y)

pygame.quit()
```

thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to implement collision detection is by using Sprites. There are several good tutorials online that walk you through Sprites and how to use them for simple collision detection. :-) This is a great feature for people just starting out with Pygame.

Here are some good videos on sprites and collision detection:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO31P0UvutM

Also, if you want a great tutorial on collisions and physics in Pygame check out Peter's website! This is what I learned from and base a lot of my Pygame collision detection program off of!

http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-physics-simulation